# Why "fmap (replicate 3) Just" has a type of "a -> [Maybe a]", In Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, functor

Recently I am learning Haskell online with [Learn You a Haskell for Great Good](http://learnyouahaskell.com/).

I have two questions:

1. `fmap (replicate 3)` is of type `Functor f=> f a -> f [a]`. Why can it be applied to `Just`?
2. Furthermore, why is `fmap (replicate 3) Just` of type `a -> [Maybe a]`, and not of type `a -> Maybe [a]`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is easy to understand if you realize that what you're `fmap`-ing over is a *function*, not a `Maybe a` value.  The type of `Just` is `a -> Maybe a`, so it falls in the `(->) a` functor, not the `Maybe` functor.  The instance of `Functor` for functions looks like

```
instance Functor ((->) a) where
    fmap g f = g . f
```

so `fmap` just becomes normal function composition!  This means that

```
fmap (replicate 3) Just
```

is the same as

```
replicate 3 . Just
```

which quite clearly has the type `a -> [Maybe a]`

---

A more "type algebra" explanation would be to line up the types and substitute until you can't anymore.  Let's start with our types, but with different variable names to make it easier to follow:

```
fmap      :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> (f a -> f b)
replicate :: Int -> c -> [c]
Just      :: x -> Maybe x
```

Then for `fmap (replicate 3)`:

```
     (replicate 3) :: c -> [c]
fmap               :: (a -> b) -> (f a -> f b)
```

So

```
(c -> [c]) ~ (a -> b)
```

Which implies

```
c   ~ a
[c] ~ b
b   ~ [a]
```

So substituting back in:

```
fmap (replicate 3) :: f c -> f [c]
```

Then what we're `fmap`-ing over is `Just`, which has the type

```
Just :: x -> Maybe x
```

Which can be rewritten in prefix form as

```
Just :: (->) x (Maybe x)
```

Or with more parentheses if we really want

```
Just :: ((->) x) (Maybe x)
```

Then

```
                   Just :: ((->) x) (Maybe x)
fmap (replicate 3)      :: f        c         -> f [c]
```

Which implies

```
((->) x) (Maybe x) ~ f c
(->) x  ~ f
Maybe x ~ c
[c] ~ [Maybe x]
```

So substituting back in:

```
fmap (replicate 3) :: ((->) x) (Maybe x) -> ((->) x) [Maybe x]
```

And back to infix notation

```
fmap (replicate 3) :: (x -> Maybe x) -> (x -> [Maybe x])
```

Then applying `Just`:

```
fmap (replicate 3) Just :: x -> [Maybe x]
```

I would like to stress here that `Maybe` being a `Functor` has nothing to do with this reduction, the only `Functor` involved is the function `Functor`.  Lists are also a `Functor`, but just because it appears in the type of `replicate` doesn't mean it matters in this case.  It is rather easy to get confused with the function

```
fmap (replicate 3) . Just :: a -> Maybe [a]
```

but that's entirely different due to the addition of the `.`.

Comment: Thanks very much. I kind of understand this. But still I have another question. "fmap (replicate 3)" type is Functor f=> f a -> f [a], which means fmap (repicate 3) should take a concrete type and return a concrete type. is "Just" a concrete type, or in other words, is "a->Maybe a" a concrete type?

Comment: @Guocheng I'll refer you to [the wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Concrete_data_type) that defines concrete data types as essentially ones that don't have type variables in them.  Are you sure "concrete type" is the terminology you're intending?

Comment: Yes,I think so. I can easily understand expressions like "fmap (replicate 3) (Just 3)" because (Just 3) is a concrete type, and  that matches fmap's type description.   Another thing confusing me is: if [Maybe a] is of type "f [a]", then what is "f" here?

Comment: @Guocheng You're getting it a bit confused.  I'll write up a better explanation above showing how the types line up, just give me a few minutes first =)

Comment: @Guocheng I think what you mean by "concrete type" is what we would technically call something with kind `*` ("kinds" are basically the "types of types", and the kind named `*` is the kind of ordinary types that have values; as opposed to things like `Maybe`, of kind `* -> *`, that need a type-level argument to create something like `Maybe Int` of kind `*`). `Just` on its own *is* of a type with kind `*`. The type of `Just` is `a -> Maybe a`; it has values which are functions. Without the infix notation that's `(->) a (Maybe a)`. The `(->) a` part is what gets matched to `f` in `f a -> f [a]`.

Comment: @Guocheng Check my edits, I hope they help explain what's going on here with this expression, and Ben is absolutely spot on with his description of the _kinds_ in this problem.

Comment: @Guocheng : perhaps you are confused because somehow you consider `Just` as being of type `Maybe a`, whereas it has actually a function type, so while it belongs to the type `Maybe a`, it also is a function injecting a value of type `a` to the type `Maybe a`. There's an ambivalence of constructors in Haskell which would really deserve a clear explanation I think, because it's not obvious at first. I think that's what @Ben explained using kinds. People coming from an [tag:ML] background, where the idiom is to define pseudo constructors to fill up that gap, will probably understand what I mean.

Answer (score 4):

The `Functor` instance that `fmap` is using is `(->) r`, not `Maybe`. Let's look at the types:

```
replicate 3        :: a -> [a]
fmap (replicate 3) :: Functor f => f a -> f [a]
Just               :: b -> Maybe b
```

1. In the expression `fmap (replicate 3) Just`, we need to match the `Functor f => f a` part with `b -> Maybe b`. The instance that this selects is the `(->) r` instance (since `Just` is a function), and we end up with `((->) r a) -> ((->) r [a])`.
2. We can expand these `(->)` applications to get this type (specialized to take a function as its argument): `(r -> a) -> (r -> [a])`.
3. Next, in order to match the type of `Just`, we need to match `r` with `b` and `a` with `Maybe b` (so that we can match `(r -> a)` with `(b -> Maybe b)`) giving us `(b -> Maybe b) -> (b -> [Maybe b])`.
4. This is the specialized type of `fmap (replicate 3)` that we can now apply to `Just` to get `fmap (replicate 3) Just :: b -> [Maybe b]`, which is the same as `a -> [Maybe a]`.

As a side note, the full type of `fmap` specialized to the `(->) r` instance is `fmap :: (a -> b) -> (r -> a) -> (r -> b)`, which means that it is the same as function composition: `fmap = (.)`.